# Problema con el comando para desbanear en discord

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un bot de discord (Mi primer bot de discord, para ser mas concretos) y al momento de crear el comando para desbanear a gente, me sale un error.

Código:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const globals = require("../globals.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'desbanear',
    description: 'Desbanea al usuario mencionado del servidor.',
    args: true,
    usage: '[id-usuario]',
    aliases: ['unban'],
    guildOnly: true,
    async execute(message, args) {
        let member = message.member;
        const guild = message.guild;
        if (member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) {
            let unbanned = args[0];
            let channel = message.channel;
            const unBannedEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor('00FF00').setAuthor(`${member.user.username}`).setTitle('Desbaneo').setDescription(`Usuario desbaneado: ${unbanned}`).setTimestamp();
            await guild.members.unban(`${unbanned}`);
            globals.ConsoleUsedCommand(member.user.username, "desbanear");
            await channel.send(unBannedEmbed);
        } else {
            await message.reply("No tienes permisos para ejecutar este comando.");
            globals.ConsoleMessageWithTimestamp(`[ATENCIÓN] Un usuario ha intentado usar un comando y no debería haberlo intentado... Usuario: ${member} Comando: Desbanear.`)
        }
    },
};
```

Error:

> (node:23412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body user_id: Value "<@!439413544564555786>" is not snowflake. at RequestHandler.execute (D:\Javigra\Javigra-bot\Javigra-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) at async RequestHandler.push (D:\Javigra\Javigra-bot\Javigra-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) at async Object.execute (D:\Javigra\Javigra-bot\Javigra-bot\commands\unban.js:18:13) (Use node --trace-warnings ...to show where the warning was created) (node:23412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag--unhandled-rejections=strict (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1) (node:23412) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

No se por que pasa esto, no veo fallos en el código, estoy usando el discord.js 12.5.1. Cualquier aportación es bienvenida :)

Comment: le hice ban a un usuario y no se como revertirlo :/, creo que el error es porque no encuentra al usuario

Answer (score 1):

Invalid Form Body user_id: Value `"**<@!439413544564555786>**" is not snowflake`.

Debes poner solo la ID no la mención osea solo: `439413544564555786`

Solo debes cambiar

```js
let unbanned = args[0];
```

Por

```js
let unbanned = message.guild.members(client.users.cache.get(args[0]));**
```

Y cambiar

```js
await guild.members.unban(`${unbanned}`);
```

Por

```js
await guild.members.unban(unbanned.id);
```